# Release toggle effect when clicking on another link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I currently have JavaScript that causes a link to change background color when clicked:

```
$(".button").click(function(){ 
    $(this).css('background-color', '#555');
});
```

And it works, but I would like that color to toggle off when I click on another link.

Comment: give it `id` and catch click !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
$(function() {
  $(".button").click(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#555');
    $(".button").not($(this)).css('background-color', '');

  });
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/tL408qLv/)

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could toggle on/off a class.

```
.toggled {
     background-color: #555;
}

//In JavaScript
$(function() {
    var allButtons = $(".button");
    allButtons.click(function() {
        allButtons.removeClass("toggled");
        $(this).addClass("toggled");
    });
});
```

Comment: `allButtons.removeClass("toggled");` can be replaced with `$('.toggled').removeClass("toggled")`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set background to clicked `.button` and remove background of another element. You can use [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to selecting sibling element of clicked `.button`.

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#555").siblings().css("background-color", "");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="button">Button1</a>
<a href="#" class="button">Button2</a>
<a href="#" class="button">Button3</a>
```